# Laravel feature test

Tags: laravel, unit-testing

OK I'm crazy confused.

This is what is happening.
I have a unit test written in the latest Laravel. And I'm writing my unit tests as both chat gpt and the auto generated unit test from the command.

So within my feature test i have two functions written that are essentially my 2 test cases.

So test case one works by its self.
And test case two works by its self.

But as soon as I uncomment the other and have two test cases in the same file i get a 404 on the last test run. Its like its caching something.

What am i doing wrong?

```php
class RegisterTest extends TestCase
{
    use DatabaseTransactions;

    private $registerRoute = '/api/v1/auth/register';

    /** @test */
    public function user_can_register()
    {
        $testUserData = [
            'first_name' => 'John',
            'last_name' => 'Doe',
            'dob' => '1987-08-05',
            'email' => 'test@example.com',
            'password' => 'Password123!',
        ];

        // Send a POST request to the login route with user's credentials
        $response = $this->post($this->registerRoute, $testUserData);

        // Assert that the registration was successful (status code 200)
        $response->assertStatus(200);

        // Assert that the user record exists in the database
        $response->assertJsonStructure(['email']);
    }

    /** @test */
    public function user_cannot_register_with_weak_password2()
    {
        $testUserData = [
            'first_name' => 'John',
            'last_name' => 'Doe',
            'dob' => '1987-08-05',
            'email' => 'test@example.com',
            'password' => 'password',
        ];

        // Send a POST request to the login route with user's credentials
                // here I was trying different ways to create the request to see if I could clear out the caching somehow. 
        $request = Request::create($this->registerRoute, 'POST', $testUserData);
        $response = $this->app->handle($request);

        // Assert that the registration was successful (status code 200)
        $this->assertEquals(400, $response->getStatusCode());
    }
}
```

error:

```
 FAIL  Tests\Feature\RegisterTest
  ✓ user can register                                                               0.07s  
  ⨯ user cannot register with weak password2                                        0.01s  
  ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────  
   FAILED  Tests\Feature\RegisterTest > user cannot register with weak password2           
  Failed asserting that 404 matches expected 400.
```

This I would expect would run two test cases and return successful on either one like it does when I run them individually.

Comment: If you run both this with proper use with $this->post(...) method, what does the 404 exception say / specify? right now you are just assuming whats wrong instead of investigating what is wrong.

Comment: I agree with @mrhn and you might post the code of the register route function so we can identify  better the problem.

Comment: You have to use `$this->actingAs($user)` and whatever method `$this->post` or `$this->get`, etc, you do not have to create a request, a route, and handle it, you are testing the framework in that case, not your code. Check my profile for more info about testing

Comment: Try using `RefreshDatabase` trait on your test class. Also you should be using `fake()` helper to create fake data for testing, and `route()` helper to avoid hard coding route URLs.